# expectation of $n$-sided die

Tags: probability, dice

Assume a dice has n sides, what is the expected value of the dice?

My solution:

The PMF of the die would be 1/n, so you would multiply this by the summation of n.

Comment: The question has no unique answer for several $n\in\{3,5,7,9,\dots\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by *"summation of $n$"*? It seems you have almost the answer, but you have to clarify a bit. I assume that the dice is numbered from $1$ to $n$? Also, conceptually a dice with $n$ side is really like an urn with numbered balls: it's pretty hopeless to try to build a dice with $n$ sides and equiprobability for value of $n$ not in $\{4,6,8,12,20\}$.

Comment: The geometry of the problem is presumably being ignored @Jean-Claude.  We should assume that the die exists (*in whatever universe is necessary for it to*) and that the sides are in fact numbered $1,2,3,\dots,n$.  If you choose to reject either of those hypotheses then the question is unanswerable.  Worded another way, let $X_n$ be a random variable defined so that $Pr(X_n = k) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n}&\text{if} ~k\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and we ask to find $E[X_n]$

Comment: Under that interpretation, the OP probably has the correct answer but phrased it very poorly, it being $\frac{1}{n}\cdot \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i\right)$.  This can of course be simplified very easily as the summation is well known.  (*as a further aside, the word "dice" is plural.  You mean to use the singular word "die"*)

Comment: @JMoravitz We have the same conclusion. Regarding the singular/plural question, I referred to [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dice). The Collins Cobuild dictionary seems to agree with the singular dice. I was surprised though.

Comment: What do you mean by  "expected value of die"?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes sorry about the poor wording. what you posted:1n⋅(∑i=1ni)1n⋅(∑i=1ni) is what i meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following definition of expected value of a discrete random variable, we have:

$$E[X_n] = \sum\limits_{x\in \Omega}x\cdot Pr(X_n=x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\cdot \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)$$

Recognizing the sum on the right as the triangle summation, one has then:

$$=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n+1}{2}$$